# Setting onclick event to pie chart on c3-angular-directive like c3.js library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

How can I set an onclick event to pie chart using [c3-angular-directive](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/)? The idea is calling console.log after clicking in a pie piece.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a solution in the [docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick) or provided [examples](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_pie.html) from c3js.

From the [c3angular-examples](http://jettro.github.io/c3-angular-directive/#examples) you can get following piece of code:

```
<chart-events on-click-data="showClick(data)"/>

graphApp.controller('GraphCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.clicked = {};
  $scope.showClick = function(data) {
    $scope.clicked = data;
  }
});
```